# IF statement on query results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement

I have the results of the query below emailed everyday 90% of the time empty. I would like to add an if statement to only send the email If (resulting row count>0)

```
 Select Orders.TransactionNumber, Orders.RepNumber, Orders.CustomerID,
        Orders.ShipToId, orders.ItemCode, Orders.Quantity, Orders.ReceivedDate, 
        Orders.TransmitStatus from (select TransactionNumber from Orders
 group by TransactionNumber
 having count (TransactionNumber = 1) as transa

 inner join Orders on Orders.TransactionNumber = transa.TransactionNumber

 where ItemCode = 9987 and ReceivedDate > DateAdd(day, -4, GetDate())
 order by ReceivedDate
```

Add here `if (counted rows>0 send the email else end)`

Comment: Is this a query or a stored procedure?  If it's the latter you could just put the IF statement directly in the sproc; if it's the former you might need to put the if statement in the code that calls the query.

Comment: Where is the e-mailing code?? What do use for mailing? PHP, ASP or VS Apps?

Comment: Take a look at my SP [here](https://davegugg.wordpress.com/2015/01/21/send-database-mail-in-html-table-format/).  Not only does it give the option to send no mail if there are no results, but it also put the email into an html table!

Comment: Are you sending an email from, say, C# code? Then check then row count there. Not inside SQL logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any DML(SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE) operations in SQLServer captured in global variable called [@@ROWCOUNT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316(v=sql.110).aspx). Use that in your case as well.

```
 Select Orders.TransactionNumber, Orders.RepNumber, Orders.CustomerID,
 Orders.ShipToId, orders.ItemCode, Orders.Quantity, Orders.ReceivedDate, 
 Orders.TransmitStatus from (select TransactionNumber from Orders
 group by TransactionNumber
 having COUNT (TransactionNumber)=1) as transa

 Inner join Orders on Orders.TransactionNumber=transa.TransactionNumber

 where ItemCode=9987 and ReceivedDate > DateADD (day, -4, GetDate() )
 Order by ReceivedDate

IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
PRINT 'send mail<your logic goes here>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you apply:

```
Orders.TransactionNumber != ""
```

to your where statement to get query results that aren't empty?

Comment: Suppose it should be `''`.